# Help with counting functions!

Tags: combinatorics, functions

how many functions $f: [7] \to [9]$ have $f(3)=8$?

I know how to count the functions $[7] \to [9]$ which is $9^7$.

But i need help to figure out how many $f(3)=8$ are there.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : The other $6$ values "on the left" can be mapped to any of the $9$ values "on the right"

Answer (score 1):

Fix $f(3)=8$, then you need to map the remaining $\{1,2,4,5,6,7\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

You should be able to then compute how many ways you can do this using the same method as you used for the computation of $9^7$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to determine the number of functions $f\colon\{1,2,4,5,6,7\}\to\{1,...,9\}$. This is, with your notation, the number of functions $[6]\to [9]$, which is...

Comment: I get this way!!! This makes sense when I see it like this! Thank you!!!

Comment: @CSmajor If you feel one of the answers answered your question, you should select the tick to the left of whichever answer you prefer so that it goes green.